# How to get the most recent n entries in a subquery group?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

MySQL 5.5 - in my table logs, how do I sum the values of the n most recent entries per user_id, for all user_ids?

```
CREATE  TABLE `logs` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `user_id` INT NULL ,
  `value` INT NULL ,
  `date_created` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT   `user_id`, SUM(`value`)
FROM     logs` as l
WHERE    (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM `logs`
          WHERE `user_id` = l.`userid` AND `date_created` > l.`date_created`) < 3
GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Please note, I have not tested it so it may need a little tweaking.

Comment: thanks aziz, this works! how "bad" does the join impact performance on big tables? (note there will be way more log rows than user_ids)

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. Unfortunately I haven't tried it on big tables, so sorry I can't comment on the performance part. My assumption is that if `user_id` is indexed then it should not be very bad. Also, I assume logs will be processed in off-time so that would help too. Please do share your findings about the performance if you happen to run this query on big tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a top n per group issue. This page has good information on what you are trying to do:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT SUM(*) `TotalSum`
  FROM `logs` log
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`date_created`) createdDate, id FROM `logs` GROUP BY `user_id`) temp
    ON temp.id=log.id
 GROUP BY log.`user_id`;
```

Comment: That query does not work, `max(date_created)` and `id` are not guaranteed  to be from the same row. So that will not work and you are not selecting the n-latest rows.

Comment: @johan: The sub query selection gets the max date_created, so that only all latest entries will be summed.

Comment: createddate and id have no relation so that alone will make it not to work and the OP want the n most recent entries, not all entries where date_created = max(date_created).